# How to import private keys from Multibit 0.5.13 to another wallet?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, multibit, private-key-import

Can anyone help trying to recover funds from my multibit wallet? I have the key file and private keys. Is there any way I can import them into another wallet? I tried to sweep them with electrum, that did not work. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

It should wort to import to electrum or bitcoin core unless you have compressed keys.